# CastCompanionLibrary: listener on start/stop button

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, castcompanionlibrary

I successfully included the CastCompanionLibrary in my media app. I use the VideoCastManager class. Now I want to put a listener on the VideoCastManager's play/stop button to catch the stop event to do something on my main screen.

Is there a `onClickListener` on the CastCompanionLibrary's start/stop button?

Is it the method `mCastManager.onPlayPauseClicked(..)`? If yes, do you have an example how to use it?

The button I am talking about is the white play button in the cast_activity.xml shown in this screenshot:

[image: cast_activity.xml with white play button]

Comment: There is no Play/Pause button in VideoCastManager to begin with. What button are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I added the screenshot of the layout "cast_activity.xml". How to get events on this button?

Comment: The activity that shows that is managed by CCL; you might want to read the tutorial on CCL which is a pdf file on the project's home page to familiarize yourself with various things that CCL does.

Comment: I did read the pdf before and now I did it again. I hoped the section "Hooking into Lifecycle Callbacks" helps me but I did not get it. I debugged all the hooks and saw when I click the Stop button `onMediaQueueUpdated` and `onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated` are called. But from this info I did not get the information that the Stop or Play button is clicked. How to get information Stop or Play button is pressed in my main activity?

Comment: if you want to use the VideoCastControllerActivity that CCL provides, then CCL handles all interactions with that activity, including button clicks, etc. If you want to have your own version of that activity, then you need to write your own and set it as the Target Activity (when you build CastConfiguration) and then handle things as you see fit.

Comment: I use `mCastManager.startVideoCastControllerActivity(context, mediaInfo, position, shouldStart)` to start the playback. I still do not understand how to get the button, clicks from this activity. Can you give me a hint how to get this events from the VideoCastControllerActivity?

Comment: Why do you need to have access to button clicks? I already said that if you want to use VideoCastControllerActivity, CCL manages that internally so you don't have access to anything there. If you want something similar that gives you access to the buttons, you need to write your own version of that Activity (implement the same interfaces that it implements, or possibly subclass VideoCastControllerActivity) and register that as your target activity.